# MongoDB query by one index, sort by antoher

Tags: mongodb

The relevant fields of the documents in my collection are the following:

```js
{
  point: {
    type: Point,
    coordinates: [15.6446464, 45.231323]
  }
  score: 24
}
```

I have a `2dsphere` index on `point` and a "normal", descending index on `score`.
I want to run the following query:

```js
db.properties.find({point: {$geoWithin: <some polygon> }}).sort({score: -1}).limit(2000)
```

Is there any way to make mongo use the index on `point` for the `find` part, and then the index on `score` for sorting?

The collection has about 700k documents, the find part can return tens of thousands of documents, each of which has up to a MB.

The current problem is that, when using the `point` index, the size of the returned collection is too big for sorting in memory. When using the `score` index, the query is too slow because of a sequential scan on coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

When executing your current query, MongoDB will only use the index on `point`. After running the `find` you will have a subset of the data and therefore Mongo can no longer use the index on `score`. You could instead create a composite index on `point` and `score` with `score` indexed in descending order. Even though the first values are unique, it helps to speed up the sorting as MongoDB can use the index to sort on `score` rather than having to scan through the entire document (which can be up to a MB in size).

The composite index follows the general rule of thumb when indexing. In general the order of an index should be:

1. Fields on which you will query for exact values.
2. Fields on which you will sort.
3. Fields on which you will query for a range of values.

However, as per your comment this composite index is not very fast and this suggest that MongoDB can't load the entire index into memory.  How much RAM have you allocated to MongoDB ? Is there any chance you can increase this ?

Comment: I've tried doing a composite index, but it won't help me because the `point` is unique for almost every document, so the `score`s would technically be random.

Comment: Are you saying that using an index for sorting a subset of the data is technically not feasible? I kind of had this feeling, but I couldn't find an explanation for it.

Comment: No you can't use an a separate index for a subset of the data. Regarding the composite key, have you tested this ?  I would expect the composite key to be the fastest in this scenario.

Comment: Yes I have, it's really slow with sorting. When sorting is removed, it's fast. But I don't see how a composite index could possibly help when the values of its first field are unique - the `score`s cannot be sorted in such an index.

Comment: See my updated answer, can you assign any more RAM to your MongoDB instances?